# How can I change the value returned in a C# get, set?

Tags: c#

I have this code that gets the value of a setting:

```
public static BTN Btns { 
   get => (BTN)App.DB.GetSet(SET.Btns, 2, typeof(BTN)); 
   set => App.DB.UpdSet(SET.Btns, (int)value); 
}
```

How can I change this so that if the value returned from `GetSet` is 1, then the value returned from the `get` will be 1 and there will be a call to `App.DB.UpdSet(SET.Btns, 2)` issued to change it in the database to a 2?

Can I use `{}` or something like that after the `=>` ?

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean.

Comment: _Can I use {} or something like that after the => ?_ - yes, you can...

Comment: But, you really should not change the value during a get... if you really have to, I suggest you change it from a property to method calls - makes things more explicit.

Comment: What have you tried? Did you read the C# language documentation, where it explains the syntax for declaring properties? I agree strongly with the recommendation against doing what you are asking; property getters _should not have side-effects_. But if you insist, everything you need is right there in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, if your property value is going to change after every `get`, you should perhaps change it to a method call - keeps things more explicit.

Secondly, you can achieve what you want by replacing your [expression bodied](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members#properties) `get` with a regular `get`, like so:

```
public static BTN Btns 
{ 
    get
    {
        var value = (BTN)App.DB.GetSet(SET.Btns, 2, typeof(BTN));

        if ((int)value == 1)
        {
            App.DB.UpdSet(SET.Btns, (int)value + 1);
        }

        return value;
    }
    set
    {
        App.DB.UpdSet(SET.Btns, (int)value);
    }
}
```